# Is it possible to drop sentences from the text with NLTK in Python?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

For example, I have a text that consists of several sentences:

"First sentence is not relevant. Second contains information about **KPI** I want to keep. Third is useless. Fourth mentions **topic** relevant for me".

In addition, I have self-constructed dictionary with words {**KPI, topic**}. 
Is it somehow possible to write a code that will keep only those sentences, where at least one word is mentioned in the dictionary? So that from the above example, only 2nd and 4th sentence will remain.

Thanks

P.S. I already have a code to tokenize the text into sentences, but leaving only "relevant" ones is not something common, as I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use list comprehensions (see example below).
But there might be a better and more pythonic solution out there.

```
sentences = ['Lorem ipsum dolor keyword sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
        'Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.',
        'Duis aute irure other_keyword dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.',
        'Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.']

vocabulary = {'keyword': 'Topic 1',
             'other_keyword': 'Topic 2'}

[sentence for sentence in sentences if any(word in sentence for word in list(vocabulary.keys()))]


>>> ['Lorem ipsum dolor keyword sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
 'Duis aute irure other_keyword dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.']
```